# How can i use getSupportFragmentManager() in a class extended by fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

i have a class which is extended from a fragment ... and i want to getSupportFragmentManager() for finding the map fragment...
this is the fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="myproject.BlankFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="this is ths map " />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
    tools:context="pk.edu.riu.mrcab.mrcabv1.MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

this is the fragment class

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
private GoogleMap mMap; 

public BlankFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are trying to access a nested Fragment, you should call [getChildFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())() instead of getSupportFragmentManager(). Please note that you should use the support library Fragment, unless you're supporting API 17+.

Comment: can u please tell me when i use  "map.addCircle() " function is gives the error in console.. not at the time of compilation ... but when i use the frgment in emulator or phone..

console error:
"    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addCircle(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addCircle(Unknown Source)"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
// and then depending on your case
fm.findFragmentById(R.id.yourId);
// or
fm.findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG");
// or
fm.getFragments(); // and then search the right one
```

This is the way I'm usually doing it.

Comment: no i did't  but ... getChildFragmentManager() work for me

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
private FragmentActivity myContext;
```

override onAttach method of your fragment :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

and call this method when you need

```
FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager(); //if lib you are using is support v4
```

or use

```
FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getFragmentManager();
```

or else you can directly call this method.

```
getFragmentManager()
```

Comment: onAttach method is depreciate in latest APIs

Comment: try  `getActivity().getFragmentManager()`